# Change native Android SIP dialing settings

Tags: automation, sip

My SIP Trunk (hooio) has a specific dialing plan:

```
[Country Code][Phone Number incl. Area Code]
```

However, all mobile carriers have a different dialing plan:

```
[Local Phone Number]   OR   
+[Country Code][Phone Number incl Area Code]
```

*The main difference here is the 'plus' character.*

All my phonebook entries are geared to work with the `+[country][number] plan`. But when I dial these using the native SIP client, I get errors - since the trunk does not like the plus (should this not be a standard?).

I'd really like to keep using this trunk, and they apparently can't or won't change their dialing plan. The only alternative is to have duplicate phonebooks for mobile vs internet calls - and I don't like my provider enough to waste time on this :(

Is there any way to configure rules for dialing with the native client, like removing the plus before dialing?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "Prefixer" (written by "253°Below") or another app "PreFixer" can make the job of cutting the "+" symbols from the numbers' beginnings. However you will need to switch the Prefixer off to make the regular GSM calls. Else you can let the Prefixer do a smarter job by cutting pluses only from the numbers which look like "+123....." transforming them into "123.....".

Also there is an application which automatically transforms all the local(short) numbers in the address book into one standard by adding country codes and area codes. Its name is "Contacts Clean-up". It might do a portion of the required job, too.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if you would link to the apps you're recommending.